# Check if DateTime in specific range

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datetime

Need to check if DateTime is in specific range. 
I think I need to calculate knowing YEAR first and last date of DST time in this year.

How would I figure "Sunday of week 2 of March" date?

```
From 1/1/2007 12:00:00 AM to 12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
  Begins at 2:00 AM on Sunday of week 2 of March
  Ends at 2:00 AM on Sunday of week 1 of November
```

For example, I need to check if 11/21/2011 is between Sunday of week 2 in March and Sunday of week 1 of November - answer should be NO

If I pass 8/8/2011 - answer should be yes.

Basically, I need to write function to check if my date belongs to daylight savings time. My only idea so far is to write loops to find 2nd week for example.

So, I would loop from Day 1 in March until I hit Sunday second time. Same thing I would loop (increment days by 1) from day 1 of November until I hit Sunday first time.

In another words, I need function to check if input data is in Daylight Savings time period. Time period defined by constraint above.

P.S. I can't use `TimeZoneInfo` since it's in Silverlight
P.P.S I can't use `DateTime.IsDaylightSavingsTime` as I don't have times with kind "local"

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is. Can you rephrase your question? Like "This is what I have" and "This is what I need" and "This is what I tried so far"

Comment: Hopefully my edit gives more info on what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this little method, check it and let me know:

```
    bool IsInDaylightSavingsTime(DateTime date)
    {
        // get second sunday in march
        DateTime _tempDateMar = new DateTime(date.Year, 3, 1);
        int secondSunDayInMar = (8 - (int)_tempDateMar.DayOfWeek) + 7;
        _tempDateMar = new DateTime(date.Year, 3, secondSunDayInMar, 2, 0, 0);

        //get first sunday in november
        DateTime _tempDateNov = new DateTime(date.Year, 11, 1);
        int firstSunDayInNov = (8 - (int)_tempDateNov.DayOfWeek);
        _tempDateNov = new DateTime(date.Year, 11, firstSunDayInNov, 2, 0, 0);

        return (date >= _tempDateMar && date <= _tempDateNov);
    }
```

Comment: Obviously your code has bugs in it but I'm marking it as answer because this is type of thought process I was looking for

Comment: well, i wrote it on the spot.. but where is the bug?

Comment: still waiting for the obvious bug

Comment: Actually, I run it through my test cases and it's good except that it doesn't take care of time part. But it's OK - overall it is working. But I went with loops anyway. I think it's easier to read and loops not that big so it is OK.

Comment: i got your point regarding the time, as i told you i did it on the spot.. I fixed it now. it will take care of the time part now.. and yes it looks little complicated but its much faster than loops..

Comment: If you want to make it 100% - change to "date < _tempDateNov"
:) At 2am first sunday of Nov daylight savings ends. It's funny - I know in one hospital they shut off computer systems before time zone change should happen so there is no problems.

Comment: I created edge case test scenarios for about 100 calculations total and it runs within 20ms on my laptop. This performance ok with me. Not webservice call as suggested in other answer.. It is OK, I get your code but to me - there is magic numbers there. Not critique, it's just reads easier to ME with loops. Loops are small. between 1 and 14 interactions depending on date. In most cases <7

Comment: u r right.. this what happens if you write code in a hurry.. any way its fixed now :)

Comment: ok, for the record.. to get the specific occurrence of a day (D) in a specific week (W) of a monthm where the first day of the month represented by (FD) use the formula: res=(7-FD+1) + (W*(Occurance-1))

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [`DateTime.IsDaylightSavingsTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method.

If your datetimes are UTC, you can convert to local and then use `IsDaylightSavingsTime()`:

```
var localDateTime = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime();
var isDaylightSavings = localDateTime.IsDaylightSavingsTime();
```

Comment: This is not what I need. All my DateTimes UTC. I need to write function to do this because I don't have "local" kinds. My app operates times from multiple time zones at the same time, there is no "local" ones

Comment: @katit, use something like: `DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
    DateTime.Parse(dateStr),
    DateTimeKind.Utc); DateTime dt = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();` to convert the UTC time to a local time.

Comment: @katit, if you have a UTC datetime, can't you convert to local in SL?

Comment: I can convert to Local but I don't need Local, I need to convert to different time zones. Let's say user looks at itinerary and user is in different time zone from departure/arrival. I know time zone of those locations and I know UTC time. I need tool like TimeZoneInfo but it's not in Silverlight

Comment: Another note. Knowing that Local time is in Daylight savings doesn't do anything to me. Another location may have different rules and time periods. So yes, I need to actually make calculations and convert times.

Comment: @katit, fair enough, although I will say if you were the downvoter, I think that was a bit harsh considering the information you provided at the time of my answer did not indicate any of this.

Comment: I removed downvote, that was my first instinct. I did say I want to calculate daylight savings time but only to make it more clear why I want to do those calculations. To me it's obvious that if someone knows about DateTimeInfo then most likely that person knows about DateTime functionality as well

Answer (score 1):

this might be enough for you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Operating on multiple TimeZones is a tricky thing. In general this problem is unsolvable by a single person efforts (unless you dedicate your life to it). If you need to support say 2-3 time zones, then it's OK to use your loop solution (AFAIK this is the only way to calculate week in .NET).

I used this code to calculate week of DST switch:

```
/// <summary>
/// Utility method for GetDaylightChanges. 
/// Searches for date defined by TransitionTime structure.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="year">Year for which create date.</param>
/// <param name="transitionTime">TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime which to use for date calculation.</param>
/// <returns>Transition time.</returns>
private static DateTime DateTimeByWeek(int year, TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transitionTime)
{
    const int DaysInWeek = 7;

    // get year and month
    DateTime switchDate = new DateTime(year, transitionTime.Month, 1);

    // move to switch day of week
    while (switchDate.DayOfWeek != transitionTime.DayOfWeek)
    {
        switchDate = switchDate.AddDays(1);
    }

    // move to week
    switchDate = switchDate.AddDays((transitionTime.Week - 1) * DaysInWeek);

    // add time
    switchDate = switchDate.AddHours(transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Hour);

    // sometimes it gives us next month...
    if (switchDate.Month != transitionTime.Month)
    {
        // ...then use previous (last) week
        return switchDate.AddDays(-DaysInWeek);
    }

    return switchDate;
}
```

obviously you don't need time, and need to replace `TransitionTime` with some custom params.

Comment: I explained why .NET doesn't help me here above. I don't need to support much - just 4 main USA time zones for now with possibility to expand later. I guess I will write those ugly loops :)
Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Oh, didn't get it first time. Then yes, go with loops. BTW see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a web service that takes a utc datetime and a timezone ID and returns the information you need - eg IsDaylightSavings. Since you would have access to the full .net framework you can use timezone functionality it has which should always be up to date as long as the system updates are installed.

Comment: Yes, and I'm sure I can find 3rd party web service and pay for it. No, it's just another piece of complexity.

Comment: I didn't say you needed to pay for one - just write your own and use the .net framework which gets the timezone information from the registry. Writing a hard coded routine for DST is flawed because the rules can and will change - they just changed back in 2007 - and barring that doing it correctly is more complex than using a web service to utilize code that has already been written and tested for handling DST rules.

Comment: Sorry, that was sarcasm about 3rd party :) I understand what you say but it's too much. This functionality have to be local. You know how you work with async calls in Silverlight? Now imagine if you need this functionality inside custom controls. It just won't work. As far as change - it's OK, I can always publish update. It's web app - update is easy. From that perspective installing server OS update or updating my app is no big difference

Comment: Yes but if you think about the lifetime of an application (not in terms of a single run of the app but in terms of how long an application could be used) it isn't a good idea (at least in my opinion) to knowingly hard code dst rules. Also if you have to deal with any other timezones there are frequent changes so this becomes more of an issue or if you deal w/ older dates (e.g. some us timezone pre-2007) then you have to deal w/ different rules based on the date. If you don't want to make a call per date then get the ranges for each zone - so 1 async call. Anyway that's my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I think about lifetime of an app too. I need US time zones only for now. If rules change - it won't be a big deal to write additional function.